# Cannot find option to install new packages or support library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android.Absolute beginner. I start learning Android Studio. So I want to know how to install new packages or support library in Android Studio to use new features. So I found [this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html). So I tried to follow it. My ADV Manager UI is so different with that one. Here is my ADV manager screenshot.

[image]

So how can I install new package or support library to android using ADV manager with the one I am using now. I cannot find packages option. I cannot find extras folder as well. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the small **Launch Standalone SDK Manager** link on the bottom left of the screenshot you just pasted. It will bring you to the old one.

Comment: Thank you . I will green up the answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the android studio click on the SDK manager icon it will open one dialog. Select the library you one to install. if you are finding difficulties to install the library, please flow the below link to install and run the hello world example.
http://javaant.com/android-studio-1-0/

Answer (score 0):

On this window in Android studio "File->Appearance & Behaviour->System settings->android SDK" click ( at bottom) "**Launch Standalone SDK Manager**"